# How to print array list in required format?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am using arraylist in java.
I have written following code:

```
public void myfunction() {
    cmdMessage="str1 : root;str2 : cisco123,12345,2345;str1 : root234;str2 : cccccc";

    String[] splitMessage = cmdMessage.split(";");
    System.out.println("string length is \n" + splitMessage.length);
    ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList> finalresult = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i= 0; i<= splitMessage.length-1;i++){

      if(splitMessage[i]!=null){
        if (splitMessage[i].contains("str1")){
            System.out.println("splitted string is "+ (splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1].trim());
            mylist.add(((splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1]).trim());
        }
        if (splitMessage[i].contains("str2")){
            System.out.println("str2 length is ..." + splitMessage[i].length());
            System.out.println("splitted str2 string is "+ (splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1].trim());
            mylist.add(((splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1]).trim());
        }
      }
      finalresult.add(mylist);  
    }
}
```

And this Java function gives result as:

```
[[root, cisco123,12345,2345, root234, cccccc],[root, cisco123,12345,2345, root234, cccccc]]
```

but I want result like:

```
[[root, cisco123,12345,2345], [root234, cccccc]]
```

I think I am missing `declaration/initialization` trick somewhere.

How do I get this result?

Comment: Please format your code more usefully in the future - it's really hard to read at the moment, with the indentation all over the place.

Comment: So you want to view the content of arraylist in different format? @vishwas

Answer (score 2):

Try to move the initialization of `mylist` into the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
public static void main(String... args) {
            String cmdMessage="str1 : root;str2 : cisco123,12345,2345;str1 :  
                   root234;str2 : cccccc";
            List myList = new ArrayList();
            String[] str = cmdMessage.split(";");
            List<List> finalList= new ArrayList();
            for(String s: str)
            {   
               if(s.contains("str1"))
            {   String[] newStr=s.split(":");
                myList.add( newStr[1].trim());
            }
                if(s.contains("str2"))
                { String[] newStr=s.split(":");
                  myList.add( newStr[1].trim());
                  finalList.add(myList);
                  myList=new ArrayList();
                    }

                }

            Iterator it = finalList.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(it.next());

            }

        }

OP: 
[root, cisco123,12345,2345]
[root234, cccccc]


finalList : [[root, cisco123,12345,2345], [root234, cccccc]]
```

Comment: I want to call a function and pass this as argument, but that function  
accepts parameter of type ArrayList<ArrayList> only..How do I convert List to Arraylist

Comment: you dont have to... ArrayList implements the List interface... So, every ArrayList is a List... You can say List instead of arraylist anywhere when passing parameters... But when adding data you have to use ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

What has happened here is regardless of which iteration of for loop is being executed, elements are added to the same list `mylist`. At the end of each iteration, 'mylist' is added to the `finalresult`. That is, in this case, two copies of same list is added to `finalresult`.

To overcome this, you have to create new list at the beginning of each iteration of the for loop, and add elements to that list. At the end of each iteration, add the newly created list to `finalresult`.

```
for (int i= 0; i<= splitMessage.length-1;i++){
  ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();

  // do something with strings...
  // ...

  finalresult.add(mylist); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i= 0; i<= splitMessage.length-1;i++){

      if(splitMessage[i]!=null){
        if (splitMessage[i].contains("str1")){
            System.out.println("splitted string is "+ (splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1].trim());
            mylist.add(((splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1]).trim());
        }
        if (splitMessage[i].contains("str2")){
            System.out.println("str2 length is ..." + splitMessage[i].length());
            System.out.println("splitted str2 string is "+ (splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1].trim());
            mylist.add(((splitMessage[i]).split(":")[1]).trim());
             finalresult.add(mylist);   // adding after str2
             mylist = new ArrayList<>();// creating new list after str
        }
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions like this:

```
public static void myfunction() {
    ArrayList<String> mylist;

    ArrayList<ArrayList> finalresult = new ArrayList<>();

    String cmdMessage = "str1 : root; str2 : cisco123,12345,2345; str1 : root234; str2 : cccccc";
    String trimmedMessage = cmdMessage.replaceAll(" ", "");
    String[] splitMessage = trimmedMessage.split("str[0-9]:");
    for(int i =0;i<splitMessage.length;i++){
        if(splitMessage[i].length()>0 && splitMessage[i].contains("root")){
            System.out.println("splitted string is " +splitMessage[i] + " " +splitMessage[i+1]);
            mylist = new ArrayList<>();
            mylist.add(splitMessage[i].replaceAll("[;,:]",""));
            mylist.add(splitMessage[i+1].replaceAll("[;:]",""));
            i +=1;
            System.out.println("Adding list "+Arrays.asList(mylist));
            finalresult.add(mylist);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(finalresult));
}
```